# Обособление тесно(?) связанного с подлежащим деепричастного оборота

Tags: пунктуация

> Они вздрогнули. И в тот же самый момент почувствовали движение воздуха, очень холодного. Стояли<kbd>**,?**</kbd>  пытаясь услышать<kbd>**,?**</kbd> - и издалека налетел шум, похожий на шум ветра.

Вопрос: нужно ли здесь обособление деепричастного оборота?

С одной стороны, ситуация подпадает под общее правило. С другой стороны, есть исключения. В частности:

> Деепричастный оборот не обособляется, *если оборот* (обычно со
>   значением обстоятельства образа действия) *тесно связан по содержанию
>   со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания*:
>
> > Она сидела чуть откинув голову (Марк.) — указывается не просто, что она сидела, а что сидела с откинутой головой; Жили Артамоновы ни  с кем не знакомясь (М.Г.) — важно не то, что жили, а что жили без всяких знакомств.

Достаточно ли сильно  оборот "пытаясь услышать" связан со сказуемым "стояли", чтобы описываемый случай являлся исключением из правила?

Ошибусь ли я, если предположу, что в приведённом примере оборот может быть как обособленным, так и не обособленным - и оба варианта не будут ошибочными?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Они вздрогнули. И в тот же самый момент почувствовали движение воздуха, очень холодного. Стояли, пытаясь (что-либо) услышать, - и издалека налетел шум, похожий на шум ветра.

**1) Деепричастный оборот обособляется,** так как обозначает второе действие (а не признак основного действия), к тому же имеет добавочное обстоятельственное значение (цели).

**Таким образом, это не обстоятельство образа действия, которое по значению сходно с наречием (наречным выражением)**.

Также интонация предложения соответствует обособлению, ударением выделяется и глагол, и деепричастный оборот, поэтому делается пауза. (При отсутствии обособления ударением выделяется только деепричастие/деепричастный оборот как смысловой центр высказывания).

Решение, скорее, однозначное.

**2) Тире авторское,** обозначает увеличенную паузу между предложениями в составе ССП, значение присоединения.

Сравнить: Я тронул их – и горестно в тиши раздался звук. 
На лице её появилась холодная неподвижность и важность – и я не узнавал её. 
Стали искать черкесов во всех кустах – и, разумеется, ничего не нашли.